# How to compare dates in Javascript without using year?

Tags: javascript

The title says it all. I'm using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/) in other areas, so I am comfortable with a solution that uses moment (or not - either way is fine). In this solution, the function would return the shortest path to the compared date. e.g. comparing 12-31 to 01-01 would return 1, not 364. Basically this is what I am looking to do:

```
var today = '08-06'; // august 6th 
var dateOne = '09-03' // september 3rd
var dateTwo = '02-29' // february 29th
var dateThree = '01-01' // january 1st

getDifferenceInDays(today, dateOne); // => 28
getDifferenceInDays(today, dateTwo); // => -159
getDifferenceInDays(today, dateThree); // => 147
```

Comment: The problem is, that difference between two days is very much dependent on the year...

Comment: I feel that you can apply some simple math to reduce the number returned (364 when year is taken into account) to what you desire

Comment: You could easily write a parser to take those values and compare with static days and months. But the main issue, is that it can not handle leap years.

Comment: Why don't you figure out how you would go about doing this with pencil and paper, and then translate that process into code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with MomentJS. The caveat is that when you initialize MomentJS date it implicitly adds the year to this year. So, the assumption is that these values are calculated for this year

```
function getDifferenceInDays(date1, date2) {
  var day1 = moment(date1,'MM-DD').dayOfYear();
  var day2 = moment(date2,'MM-DD').dayOfYear();
  var diff1=(day2 - day1)
  var diff2=365- Math.abs(diff1)
  if (Math.abs(diff1)>Math.abs(diff2)) {
     return diff2;
  } else {
     return diff1;
  }
}

var today = '08-06'; // august 6th 
var dateOne = '09-03' // september 3rd
var dateTwo = '02-29' // february 29th
var dateThree = '01-01' // january 1st
console.log(";;;;")
console.log(getDifferenceInDays(today, dateOne)); // => 28
console.log(getDifferenceInDays(today, dateTwo)); // => -159
console.log(getDifferenceInDays(today, dateThree)); // => 147
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2brgf4r/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this pretty easily with [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) by getting the month and day of the month from your Date object.

```
var getDifferenceInDays = function(date1, date2) {
  var day1 = date1.dayOfYear();
  var day2 = date2.dayOfYear();

  if (Math.abs(day1 - day2) < (365 - Math.abs(day2 - day1))) {
    return Math.abs(day1 - day2);
  } else {
    return (365 - Math.abs(day1 - day2));
  }
}
```

Moment's "dayOfYear()" function returns the day of the year (a number between 1 and 366). Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that this method takes in 2 Date objects, but with Moment, you could easily convert your "MM-DD" format into a Date object

Comment: downvoted because it gives different result from what the OP wanted when tried

Comment: Sorry, slight logic error. Try it again - should work now.